# update document with req.user object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm writing an express app in node.js and am having issues updating this model.

```
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    comment: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        max: 200
    },
    rating: { type: Number, trim: true, max: 10, min: 0 },
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 
    created: { type: Date, default:Date.now }
}); 


var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: { type: String, trim: true, max: 30 },
    venue: { type: String, trim: true, max: 30 },
    critic_review: String,
    user_reviews: [reviewSchema],  
});
```

This route defined below...

**app.js**

```
app.put('/event/:id/reviews', routes.events.addReview)
```

activates this function

**routes/events.js**

```
    // Route to update Event with a new Review
    exports.addReview = function(req, res, next) { 
        if(!req.params.id) return next(new Error('No event ID.'));
        req.models.User.findById(req.user, function(error, user) {

            // check if user's username is available to this route 
            if (req.user.username){console.log(req.user.username)}
            req.models.Event.findByIdAndUpdate(
                _id = req.params.id,
                {$push: {"user_reviews": 
                {comment: req.body.comment,    // correct
                 rating: req.body.rating,      // correct 
                 user: req.user.username       // causes error, see below
                }}},
                {safe: true},
                function(err, results)
                {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                });
             res.redirect('/event');
            });
         }
```

which is supposed to update the event model. Below is part of the jade template

**views/event.jade**

```
each review in item.user_reviews
    li #{review.user} says: #{review.comment} #{review.rating} # {review.created}
```

which gives the following output at localhost:3000/event

```
says: test 5 Thu Jul 02 2015 17:51:53 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

To check if #{review.user} was null or empty I added the conditional console log (event.js : line 6) which gave the console output

```
myname
```

So req.user.username is available, but if I try to $push it I get this error:

**[Error: Unable to invalidate a sub-document that has not been added to an array]**

I also tried passing

```
 user : req.session.passport.user
```

to $push and then grab the values from the template but this didn't work either.

I've spent some time looking up this error message but I cant find anything of use. If anybody is able to shed any light on this i'd be very grateful! Thank you for reading.

**EDIT**

passport configuration in **app.js**

```
var User = require('./models/user');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// Registration 
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username }), req.body.password,  function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.render('register', {info: "Sorry. That email already exists. Try again."});
        }

        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
            console.log('Attempting auth');
            res.render('profile', { user: user });
            //res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
});

// Login authentication
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Exposed models to app in **app.js**

```
// Expose models to app. 
app.use(function(req, res, next){ 
    if( !models.Article || !models.User || !models.Event ) 
        return next(new Error('No models.'));
    req.models = models;
    return next();
});
```

Comment: Have you also verified that the schema exists in Mongo as you have defined in the schema? I see a schema, but I don't see you using a model for Mongoose. Why would you have a model in your request object as `req.models.User`?

Comment: @signus I have updated my question, for your last question I believe you have req.models.User.method where method would be find, findById, Update etc.. to retrieve and modify mongoDB through mongoose. Apologies if I've misunderstood you. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Not too sure I understand what you mean. Could you show the models you are importing? I also think it does you no good to put your models into your request object, just call the models on their own.

Comment: i'm importing the model (top peice of code) into app.js (via bottom peice of code). Also, call models this way because its the convention used here 
 https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RyEHBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=req.models.Article&source=bl&ots=DRUQPQyMC0&sig=dbN-pwle9FKa8iwAfy44EuGaPi0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lY2VVcLRDMG7-AGVk6eIBg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=req.models.Article&f=false 

calling models on their own i.e Event.findByIdAndUpdate gives me undefined errors ):

Comment: The top piece of code is a schema, not a model. You need to create a model from the schema like `var reviewModel = mongoose.Model('Review', reviewSchema);`